# Where is particle edit radius in Blender 2.8?

Tags: particles, selection-tools, hair

Ok Im trying to do hair here in latest 2.8 and can't figure out how to change radius/strength. Where are these tools?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.80 the tool settings that you previously found in the toolbar region can be found at the top of the 3D Viewport. As there is limited space only the common options are visible with others in a menu to the right.

[image: tool settings header]

You can also find the same options in the properties editor.

[image: tool settings in the properties editor]